# VB Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, file-io

I am simply trying to load an xml file and I cannot figure out how.  Here is my code:

```
Dim root As Xml.XmlDocument = Nothing
root.Load(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "C:\XMLFile1.xml")
```

It compiles without errors but then gives me "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when I step through the debugger and it reaches that second line.  The file exists where it is supposed to.  I've tried almost every variation of the above lines that I could find online (ie with just the path within the parentheses in the second line etc) but still get the same issue.

Comment: `DirctoryPath` & "C:\XMLFile1.xml" will result in something like "C:\MyDirectoryPath\C:\XMLFile1.xml", which is not what you want, I think.  Try `My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "XMLFile1.xml"`.

Comment: You can use a `Nothing` to do .... Nothing

Comment: Calling method `Load` on `Nothing` sounds fun.

Comment: `Dim root As Xml.XmlDocument = Nothing : Nothing.Load(Nothing)`

Comment: To combine paths, it is a Good Idea to use [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as it will take care of leading/trailing path separators for you. And please take note of Tim's comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look closely at what you're doing:

```
Dim root As Xml.XmlDocument = Nothing
```

This line says to create a variable called `root` but set it to `Nothing`.  That is, don't assign it an instance of any actual object.  Then:

```
root.Load()
```

You're trying to *use* the object, which you just *explicitly* defined as not being an object.

The error has nothing to do with your XML file, it never gets that far.  You need an actual instance of an object before you can call members of that object.  I think what you're looking for is this:

```
Dim root As New XmlDocument
root.Load(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "C:\XMLFile1.xml")
```

This creates an instance of an `XmlDocument` object and *then* invokes the `Load` member on that object.  (Though I think the path is wrong, but that's another issue entirely.  I can't imagine any path information *preceeding* the drive letter...)

Comment: Maybe you should change this part: `My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "C:\XMLFile1.xml"` ;)

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå: I agree completely, but change it to what?  I don't know what the path of the file is.  I've indicated that this path is *very likely* to be incorrect, but determining the correct path is up to the OP.

Comment: Yeah, I saw the (..) a little late, and I totally agree.

Comment: That worked, thanks for the informative response, I'm new to vb